# What would be the best approach to store data offline when working with web application in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json, sqlite, web-applications, json.net

I am writing a web application that will mostly be used on a mobile devices in asp.net C#. I was wondering what would be the best way to store data offline. This theory is what I have on mind:

**When the user first access the website I want my code to export the entire schema and the data from the MSSQL database dynamically to JSON file (if it's possible) then the next step is to take that generated JSON file and create a local SQLite database with all the data from JSON. So later my application can read from it while the user is not online**

please let me know what do you think or if this is not going to work because of something I am missing.

Thank you,

Comment: Below link will help you http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5-Client-Side/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, but it all depends on what your mobile app is like, what kind of data you are transferring (structured or unstructured), whether or not the ASP.NET site needs to serve web clients, etc.

- Consider writing a mobile app using Cordova/PhoneGap. There are native plugins for various device platforms where you can store the data locally.
- BreezeJS (http://www.breezejs.com/) is a native JavaScript framework for data access, including sync.
- If you are creating a native iOS app, consider [RestKit](http://restkit.org/).
- If you decide you want to create a native cross-platform app, you could use a technology such as Xamarin and use [Azure Mobile Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data/) to do data sync. You would have to convert your app to be a WebAPI however, which might not be feasible. (Disclosure: I work on this project)
- Amazon has a sync service called [Cognito](http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/).

Comment: First, thank you for you reply. I will research more this weekend about the technologies you mentioned above. The app is not going to be a native app. It will be a responsive web app using Twitter bootstrap styling.